# Performance comparison of different activation functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, activation-function

I was trying to find a way to compare the test accuracy and test loss of different activation functions (such as tanh, sigmoid, relu), so I came up with this script:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras import models
from keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf 
import keras.backend as K
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y, random_state=42)
train_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)
test_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)

def test_activation_functions(act):
    K.clear_session()
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation=act, input_shape=(4,)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X_train, train_labels, epochs=20, batch_size=40 , verbose=0)
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, test_labels, verbose=0)
    del model
    return test_loss , test_acc

def loop(act, iters):
    test_losses = []
    test_accs = []
    for i in tqdm(range(iters)):
        test_loss , test_acc = test_activation_functions(act)
        test_losses.append(test_loss)
        test_accs.append(test_acc)

    return test_losses , test_accs

def plot_histograms(test_losses, test_accs):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    plt.hist(test_losses, bins=20)
    plt.title(f"Average Test Losses {round(np.average(test_losses), 4)}, \n std:{round(np.std(test_losses),4)}")
    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plt.hist(test_accs, bins=20)
    plt.title(f"Average Test Accuracy = {round(np.average(test_accs), 4)}, \n std = {round(np.std(test_accs), 4)}")
    plt.show()

def main():
   
    test_losses_relu , test_accs_relu = loop(tf.keras.activations.relu, 1000)
    test_losses_sigmoid , test_accs_sigmoid = loop(tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, 1000)
    test_losses_tanh , test_accs_tanh = loop(tf.keras.activations.tanh, 1000)

    plot_histograms(test_losses_relu, test_accs_relu)
    plot_histograms(test_losses_sigmoid, test_accs_sigmoid)
    plot_histograms(test_losses_tanh, test_accs_tanh)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Before I get to my main question: am I clearing the TensorFlow sessions correctly? or my code can be optimized further?

Now the main question I have is, is this implementation reasonable? For example, here are the results of the loop of 1000 iterations:

ReLU:

[image]

Sigmoid:

[image]

Tanh:

[image]

However, I don't understand why tanh is performing better than relu. (Maybe on a deeper model relu - due to vanishing gradient -  is better than tanh? )

So, Is there a more systematic way to "benchmark" these activation functions?

Comment: This [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-16-2248-9_34) might be helpful

Comment: maybe this [link](https://github.com/4uiiurz1/keras-arcface) and [plot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/4uiiurz1/keras-arcface/master/figures/mnist_vgg8_3d.png) in this repo give you idea